# How to terminates a process with all termination signals ignored?

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

I'm writing my own shell. In a shell process, all the termination signals should be ignored. If I don't implement a built in `exit` command, how can I terminate my shell process?

I've tried to force the terminal to quit. However doing this makes it impossible to open a terminal again!

OS X Terminal :

```
[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]

[forkpty: Resource temporarily unavailable]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

iTerm :

```
Unable to Fork!

iTerm cannot launch the program for this session.
```

Could somebody tell me what's going on here? It seems that if I force the terminal to quit, some resources would not be free; so next time I try to open a terminal, the resources are unavailable.

Comment: Without access to your code, we can only speculate. But it seems like you have a rather severe resource leak. Does your code retry aggressively when something fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst case scenario: open a new terminal somewhere else and terminate your shell.

Let's say your shell is called `nmzsh`:

Open another terminal and:

```
$ ps aux | grep nmzsh # find the pid
1000      1595  0.0  0.0  47408  5080 tty1     S+   11:46   0:00 nmzsh
1000     12094  0.0  0.0  13652   948 pts/7    S+   15:21   0:00 grep nmzsh
$ kill -KILL 1595 # murder nmzsh in cold blood
```

If you want to kill all of the `nmzsh` processes that are running, then it's much simpler (and also more dangerous):

```
$ killall -KILL nmzsh # mass murder all of the nmzsh
```

Comment: @Nmzzz yep, heh :) - if this solved your problem, please mark it as the solution.